# "Get" request works (?) but not displaying data

Tags: node.js, angular, rest

I'm trying to do a crud with angular and node.

My rest API  is completed (made with node and mysql);

Trying to display my JSON data at the HTML template, but I'm not being successful...

Thank you if you could help me :)

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Produto} from './produto';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class ProductService {

constructor(private _http : Http){ }

getProdutos(): Observable<Produto[]>{
    return this._http
        .get("http://localhost:8080/produtos").pipe(
        map(res => res.json()));
    }

}
```

Html:

```
             <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>

        <!-- Use *ngFor directive to loop throught our list of products. -->
        <tr *ngFor="let produto of produtos">
            <td>{{produto.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{produto.descricao}}</td>
            <td>{{produto.valor}}</td>
            <td>{{produto.src}}</td>
            <td>
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from 
'@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Produto } from '../produto';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-read-products',
    templateUrl: './read-products.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./read-products.component.css'],
    providers: [ProductService]
})

export class ReadProductsComponent implements OnInit {

    produtos: Produto[];

    constructor(private productService: ProductService){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.productService.getProdutos()
            .subscribe(produtos =>
                this.produtos=produtos['records']
            );
    }
}
```

Class:

```
export class Produto {
  constructor(
      public produto_id: number,
      public nome: string,
      public descricao: string,
      public valor: number,
      public src: string
  ){}
}
```

My json response (when goes to the link):

```
[{"produto_id":10,"nome":"caderno","descricao":"maycon","valor":23.2212,"src":"aasssaa"}]
```

Have more classes in my project, if someone thinks that the problem is in another, just tell...

OBS: CREATED WITH ANGULAR CLI AND FOLLOWING THIS [TUTORIAL](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2016/12/angular-crud-tutorial.html)

Comment: put you'r code into http://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get un-named array from backend then you should assign result directly to productos :

```
this.productService.getProdutos()
        .subscribe(produtos =>
            this.produtos=produtos
        );
```

If you get your array data here in productos then your HTML ngFor loop will work correctly :

```
<tr *ngFor="let produto of produtos">
        <td>{{produto.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{produto.descricao}}</td>
        <td>{{produto.valor}}</td>
        <td>{{produto.src}}</td>
        <td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the changed response inside map function. Like this

```
return this._http
        .get("http://localhost:8080/produtos").pipe(
        map(res => 
             return res.json()));
    }
```

Do a console.log to check whether you are receiving the data and identify the structure of the data.  For the json response you have mentioned , in your component just assign it directly to the array

`this.produtos=produtos;`

Hope this helps.